# remove duplicate Python environments sharing the same base

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, conda, environment

I've observed multiple Python environments currently running, all utilizing a common base, as illustrated by the accompanying Python environment manager image. What would be the most effective approach to eliminating these duplicate environments?

[Environment Images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3PhJz.png)

Comment: I don't think you have duplicate environments, that looks like VSCode is just showing you the same environment (the conda base environment) multiple times.  What does `conda env list` give you in the terminal?

Answer (score 0):

The page you show is not the page brought up by the official extension **[Python](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python)**, if you use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> --> `Python: Select Interpreter` to open the **Select Interpreter** page this should show all the pyhton environments properly.

The page you show is provided by the *Python Environment Manager* extension, uninstalling and reinstalling might solve the problem.